# How can i iterate inside an append or html method in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I can't figure out how can i perform $.each in append or html method if possible.
For example:

i have an **array**

```
cities = [Larissa,Athens,Patra];
```

and i want to create the **following code:**

```
` $('#cities').html(' <label for="cities">Select City</label><select name="cities" id="city">' +
                                          ' <option value="Larissa">Larissa</option> ' +
                                          ' <option value="Athens">Athens</option> ' +
                                          ' <option value="Thessaloniki">Thessaloniki</option> ' +
                                          ' <option value="Patra">Patra</option>' +'</select>');`
```

How can I create the option value and the name dynamically based on my array.
Any Insight is welcomed Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it using `$.each` as you originally asked.

```js
var cities = ['Larissa','Athens','Patra'];

$.each(cities, function(index, city){
  $('select').append('<option value="' + city + '">' + city + '</option>')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods.

```
var cities = ['Larissa', 'Athens', 'Patra'];

$('#cities').html(' <label for="cities">Select City</label><select name="cities" id="city">' +
  cities.map(function(v) {
    return '<option value="' + v + '">' + v + '</option> ';
  }).join('') + '</select>'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo using `$.append()` and `$.map()` :

```js
var cities = ['Larissa', 'Athens', 'Patra'];

$('#cities').append(
 // add label
    $('<label>', {
        for: "cities",
        text: "Select City"
    }) // end of label
    , 
    // followed by the select with its options
    $('<select>', {
        name: 'cities',
        id: 'city'
    }).append( // appending the options in select
     $.map(cities, function(val, ndx){
         return $('<option>', {
             value : val,
                text : val
            })
        })
    ) // end of select
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cities">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
var cities = ['Larissa','Athens','Patra'];
var select = $('<select>');
$(cities).each(function (index, item) {
    select.append('<option>'+item+'</option>')
})
$('#cities').html(' <label for="cities">Select City</label>');
$('#cities').append(select);
```

[See working example](https://jsfiddle.net/r3b1ow3h/)